# Axis labels are invisible?

Tags: matlab, label, subplot

I have the following code:

```
figure(1);
suptitle('Percentage of games won with board size');
count = 0;
% relation of board size and the game outcome
for i = 1:4 % number combination of player and opponent
    for j = 1:4 % starting indexes for board sizes
        percentageStepResult = [sum(sizeResultVec{i}(j:4:120) == 1), sum(sizeResultVec{i}(j:4:120) == -1), sum(sizeResultVec{i}(j:4:120) == 0)];
        count = count + 1;
        handle = subplot(4, 4, count);
        xlabel('x axis');
        ylabel('y axis');
        pie(percentageStepResult)
    end
end
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

Why doesn't this display the labels at all?  I'm trying to move towards having one xlabel and one ylabel for the whole plot, but I'm confused as to why they won't even display for the individual subplots.

Comment: Use `text` to affect axis labels.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `X` and `Y` axis make little sense to me for a `pie` chart, and probably for the *Mathworks* too, so they decided to "hide" these meaningless labels.

The labels are not displayed because each axe underlying the pie chart has its  `visible` property set to `'off'`. This hides everything about the axe (i.e. ticks, grid line, background color, etc...).

If they are not meaningless to you and you really want the labels to be displayed, you have to set the axes `visible` property to `'on'`. The code below is inspired from your example and shows you how to do it.

The problem with this method, is that you will have to manually 'hide' everything else you do not want to see. This is why I hid the ticks, the background and the grid lines, but the axe border will remain.

```
count = 0 ;
hdl = zeros(4,4) ;
for i = 1:4 %// number combination of player and opponent
    for j = 1:4 %// starting indexes for board sizes
        percentageStepResult = rand(4,1) ;
        count = count + 1 ;
        hdl(i,j) = subplot(4, 4, count) ;
        pie(percentageStepResult)
        set( hdl(i,j) , 'Visible','on' )            %// set the underlying axes to visible
        set( hdl(i,j) , 'Color','none' )            %// set the axes background color to nothing (transparent)
        set( hdl(i,j) , 'XTick',[] , 'YTick',[] )   %// remove the 'X' and 'Y' ticks
        grid off                                    %// make sure there is no grid lines
        xlabel('x axis');
        ylabel('y axis');
    end
end
```

Note that I also changed the variable which holds the *handles* to the axes. It is not a good idea to call something `handle` as it is the name of a Matlab built in function. I also put these handles in an array so you can set the axes properties later on if you'd like.

Also note that you can combine all the calls to `set( hdl(i,j) , ... )` into one line, I only developed it here for clarity.

edit: Look at the answers from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838789/remove-only-axis-lines-without-affecting-ticks-and-tick-labels-in-matlab) if you want to also hide the axe border (X0 and Y0 lines).

---

This showed you how to force each axe label to be displayed, but in practice it is very messy. I would recommend instead to just create `text` objects and work out how to position them near each pie. At least you won't have to manage the visibility of everything else manually.

Comment: If all he wants is an axis for the entire grouping of plots, it seems like it would make more sense to just make a dummy axis and remove the background. Or create a couple text labels with uicontrol.

Comment: @excaza, totally agree with you. The method I showed is only to explain and answer _why do the labels not appears_. I would just go with `text` objects in his case.