# How to add a gap between the axes and the plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab-figure

I use code like this to make a plot in MATLAB 2015:

```
plot(rand(1,40))
box off
ax=gca;
ax.TickDir='out';
ax.TickLength=3*ax.TickLength;
```

[image: What MATLAB gives by default]]

I want to put a bit of distance between the axes and the plot like in the figure below, which I made using Photoshop:

[image: What I want it to look like]

How can I do this?

Comment: Suggest you add more detail to your question. Also add code you've attempted. Don't ask us to spoonfeed you.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way to do it, but:

- I don't know if it's the "right" way.
- It's only good for static images (i.e. if you zoom/pan the plot, the bounds won't change accordingly).

The idea is you create two more `axes` and specify their positions such that they're far enough from your data, then hide the original `axes` (either fully or partially), which gives the desired result:

```matlab
%% // Create axes and plot something:
figure();
hA(1) = axes;
hA(2) = copyobj(hA(1),gcf); 
hA(3) = copyobj(hA(1),gcf);
plot(hA(1),rand(1,40));
%% // Add the new axes:
%// Move them around
FRACTION_OF_POSITION = 0.6;
hA(2).Position(1) = FRACTION_OF_POSITION*hA(2).Position(1);
hA(3).Position(2) = FRACTION_OF_POSITION*hA(3).Position(2);
%// Change their style
hA(2).Color = 'none'; hA(3).Color = 'none';
hA(2).XTick = []; hA(3).YTick = [];
hA(2).XRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';
hA(3).YRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';
%% // Remove the box/ticks/labels of the original axes:
if true
%// Alternative 1 (Remove everything at once, including background):
  set(hA(1),'Visible','off')
else
%// Alternative 2 (Remove only certain elements):
  hA(1).Box = 'off';
  hA(1).XRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';
  hA(1).YRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';
end
```

Which results in:

[image: The result]

---

Additional considerations:

- If you `copyobj` the axes before plotting, the axis tick values would be default - you probably don't want that. You will have to set the ticks and labels manually, OR, `copyobj` after plotting but then delete the `line` child-objects of `hA(2:3)`.
- If you want to support zoom/pan behavior, this might be acheivable using [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html).

---

**Credits**: the idea to use `.XRuler.Axle` was taken from Dan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32073460/3372061), who in turn took it from [UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-rulers).