# Force axes to initialize before plotting

Tags: matlab

I seek to remove borders using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742225/10133797), where `pause` doesn't work.

```matlab
plot([1 2])
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Axle.LineStyle = 'none';
```

throws

```
Property assignment is not allowed when the object is empty.
Use subscripted assignment to create an array element.
```

Here, `pause` works, but in my context (large `tiledlayout`) let's say[*] it doesn't. Replacing last line with `ax.XRuler.Axle` gives

```
  0×0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
```

With pause, it gives

```
LineStrip
```

I presumed the error message is suggesting `subsasgn`, which I've tried, but it's two `.` accesses. I've not found the `LineStrip` object anywhere.

Are there any hacks to this situation? Or better solutions (I can re-title the question)? The goal is to simply make the borders disappear, without disabling `xlabel` & `ylabel`.

<sub>[*] `pause(.01)` greatly slows down everything for some reason, also some tiles are skipped (on purpose), though I suppose I could hack that part with another slowdown</sub>

Comment: use `drawnow` to force plotting without a delay. As far as I understand `ax.XRuler.Axle` _is_ the plot (or part of it), so you can't make it exist before its plotted.

Comment: Same problem as `pause(.01)`

Comment: _"can't make it exist before its plotted"_ since it's OOP I'm thinking maybe there's an internal hack to assign the relevant objects in vanilla state without breaking things

Comment: Did you try `axis off`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo disables `xlabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the command `ax=gca` is executed before the graphic engine can create the plot, as the graphic engine is called asynchronously from the executing of the script.

If your problem is that the equivalent `plot` command takes too long before the axis can be handled, a possible solution is to force an axis creation (very fast) and then plot in that axis after tuning it.

```
axes
drawnow % you still need this, but should not slow anything down, as the axes call should be very fast
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Axle.LineStyle = 'none';
plot([1 2])
```

For `tiledlayout`:

```matlab
figobj = tiledlayout(2, 3);
for i=1:prod(figobj.GridSize)
    nexttile
end
drawnow
% do plotting ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `tiledlayout`. Something equivalent I can do there, like iterate all its axes and do a quick assignment?

Comment: Ok I found it; `while true` -- `try` -- `nexttile` -- `catch` -- `break`. Neat workaround! I'll see if there's problems this doesn't account for.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon hum let me play with it. Admittedly I did find `subplot` better in the past, it gives me more granular control over the plot

Comment: Bottom of [subplots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) ("Alternate functionality") appears to suggest `tiledlayout` is more versatile, though I could be misreading. I have a large planned out grid, would take some work to rewrite with `subplot`.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon yeah, I think I've been doing MATLAB for too long. All that is suggested by mathworks that `tiledlayout` does is problems that I have had long ago and have solved long ago. True that `tiledlayout` does more things for you, but depending on the granularity of control you may want, this is not a positive thing. You seem to be (seing your questions) of the type that likes to have extreme granular control.

Comment: Cool! [Reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4GiD.png) -- [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16495490/135678733-e1e49ac9-fd39-48f6-b9f9-6db755afff63.gif) (-- [source](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78623/50076)), no GIF yet. (Got issues with `suplabel` and `exportgraphics` but these seem unrelated). Here's to hoping those 3D ones aren't much pain. -- Good to know re: `subplot`, `tiledlayout` suffices here.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon cool! for exporting figs: I would greatly suggests using `export_fig` from the FEX/github, its the most reliable way to produce publication quality figures with no weird rendering artifacts.